# Cake php 3.4 login is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

> appcontroller page

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
      'authenticate'=>[
        'Form'=>[
          'Fields' => [
            'username'=>'email',
            'password'=>'password'
          ]
        ]
      ],   
     'loginAction'=>[
       'controller'=>'Users',
       'action' =>'login'
     ]
    ]);    
}
```

> Model/entity/user.php

```
protected function _setPassword($password){
    return(new DefaultPasswordHasher)->Hash($password);
}
```

> login.ctp

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login </h2>

        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password')); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->submit('Login',array('class'=>'button')); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

> UsersController.php

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user)
        {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'posts']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login Username and password in Tokyo');
        }
    }
}
```

It is not getting logging even after entering correct password. What's the problem? I am trying to get log in for a long time but it always fails.

Comment: nat a capital "H" in Hash its hash

Comment: @AmanRawat PHP class methods are case-insensitive.